# how to use Sharingan for newspaper text extraction?

Tags: opencv, newspaper3k

I want to test Sharingan for newspaper text extraction https://github.com/vipul-sharma20/sharingan, but I didn't understand how to use it.

I cloned the project, installed requirements.

What else, is there any example to start with?

Comment: you should ask the author. such questions don't belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sharingan is used for text extraction from images.  Have you looked at OpenCV, which Sharingan uses?